# error=2, No such file or directory at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)

Tags: java

I wrote one java program to periodically monitor the status of the devices using `fping` protocol. It will execute the `fping` command for every 5 mins. I got an above exception sometimes only. We are using this directory (/usr/local/bin/). This where `fping` installed. Please suggest.

```
public static List<String> executeProcess(String command,List<String> args,String dirPath) throws Exception {

        // delegate
        args.add(0,command);
        args.add(1,FpingSession.FPING_RETRY);
        args.add(2,FpingSession.FPING_RETRY_VALUE);
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        if(dirPath!=null && !dirPath.isEmpty())
            processBuilder.directory(new File(dirPath));

        List<String> stringList;
        Process process = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            process = processBuilder.start();

            inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
            while (true) {
                // next line
                final String string = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (string == null) {
                    break;
                }
                // track
                stringList.add(string);
            }
        } finally{
            if (process != null)
                process.destroy();
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
            if (inputStreamReader != null)
                inputStreamReader.close();
            if (bufferedReader != null)
                bufferedReader.close();
        }
        // done

        return stringList;
}
```

Comment: Who owns the directory: `/usr/local/bin/`? what are the permissions on the directory ?

Comment: when i restart the application that exception not came..

Comment: Is it /usr/local/bin or /usr/local/sbin ?

Comment: sorry folder name mentioned wrongly in question. correct path was (/usr/local/sbin/ )

Comment: []$ ll /usr/local/sbin/fping -rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 137929 Apr 20 2017 /usr/local/sbin/fping

Comment: anybody can help to solve the problem?